# Integral $ \int_E \frac{1}{x^ay^b}dxdy \qquad E={x>0,y>0,xy \geq 1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I'm asked to compute:
$$ \int_E \frac{1}{x^ay^b}dxdy \qquad E={x>0,y>0,xy \geq} 1$$
but I'm really finding difficulties in doing it as the domain is unlimited. I can pretty much solve this kind of integrals when the domain is limited and there is a problem in one or more than one points, but how can I compute this in an efficient way?
I am also a little bit concerned about polar coordinates: I think that it could be a good way to do it, but people here, on other questions, told me that I should avoid doing it to prevent other issues. 
Can you please help me understanding how to proceed in problems like this one?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

We notice that we can express the domain as $E=\{x>0, y>\frac{1}{x}\}$ so we have:

$$\int_E \frac{1}{x^ay^b}dxdy= \int_0^{+\infty}\left(\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^ay^b}dy\right)dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^a}\left[ \frac{1}{(1-b)y^{b-1}} \right]_{\frac{1}{x}}^{\infty}dx$$

Let's suppose $b>1$ (otherwise the integral diverges):
$$\frac{-1}{b-1}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^a}x^{b-1}dx=\frac{-1}{b-1}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^{a-b+1}}dx$$
But now we have something that diverges for all values of $a,b$ as it has both problems in $0$ and at $\infty$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The condintions describing $E$ are equivalent to $0<x<\infty$ and $1/x \leq y < \infty$ (this already implies $y>0$). So you could first integrate over $y$, form $1/x$ to $\infty$, and then over $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$. Does that make sense?

Comment: It seems like the integral diverges though... Is that a possible answer?

Comment: Sure it is a possible answer and your process it's exactly what I did. But I don't feel so confident about it.. I don't know if it is formally correct.

Comment: If the double integral converges, then both of the iterated integrals must also converge. (Going the other way is not always true, but double Integral $\implies$ iterated integrals always holds.) Since one of the iterated integrals diverges, the double integral cannot converge.

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you mean by iterated integrals? And, btw, if you want to review my answer I'll be glad to upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: When you integrate with respect to $y$ first, then with respect to $x$, that is an iterated integral. If you integrate with respect to $x$ first, then with respect to $y$, that is the other iterated integral. The double integral integrates both together. When the function is continuous and the region is bounded, all three will diverge or converge to the same limit together. But for discontinuous functions or unbounded regions, convergence of the double integral still implies convergence of the iterateds to the same value, but divergence of the double does not imply divergence of the iterateds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you want to post an answer I'll upvote you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because convergence of the double integral $$\int_E \frac{dxdy}{x^ay^b}$$ would imply convergence of both the iterated integrals $$\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^a}\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{dy}{y^b}dx$$ and $$\int_0^\infty \frac 1{y^b}\int_{1/y}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^a}dy,$$ the fact that $\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^a}\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{dy}{y^b}dx$ diverges to $\infty$ is enough to prove that $\int_E \frac{dxdy}{x^ay^b}$ does not converge.

(It is not enough to prove it diverges to $\infty$ as well. It could potentially diverge in other ways, but it cannot converge while one of the iterated integrals diverges.)

So your calculation is enough to show the integral does not converge.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)